# Kubernetes - resolve hostname of a service

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to perform a call to my echo-server but I can not figure out what's the hostname of my service:

```
orion:webanalytics papaburger$ kubectl get services -n web-analytics
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)      AGE
echo-server            ClusterIP   10.100.92.251    <none>        80/TCP       87m
web-api                ClusterIP   10.100.92.250    <none>        8080/TCP     87m
```

I have tried to reach using `kubectl exec -it curl-curl0 -- curl http://web-analytics.echo-server.svc.cluster.local/heythere` but it fails:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'web-analytics.echo-server.svc.cluster.local'
```

If I change `web-analytics.echo-server.svc.cluster.local` to cluster ip, it works.

How can I make my pods (web-api) reach the echo server?

edit:

```
orion:webanalytics papaburger$ kubectl get ep -n web-analytics
NAME                   ENDPOINTS             AGE
echo-server            172.16.187.247:80     95m
web-api                172.16.184.217:8080   95m
```

Comment: where is the web-analytics service described? as far as I can see the output you describe it say it's diffrent service

Comment: Check the update

Comment: Why the service name is diffrent?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm new to K8s

Comment: I can not see the web-analytics service name?

Comment: I was mounting hostname as <namespace>.<servicename>.svc.cluster.local. Isn't right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218768/discussion-between-placplacboom-and-dashrath-mundkar).

Comment: can you describe the service ?   kubectl describe service myymlservice -n OptionalIfIHaveOneNamespaceName

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be like this

the service name is always like this

`<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local`

```
kubectl exec -it curl-curl0 -- curl http://echo-servcer.web-analytics.svc.cluster.local/heythere
```

or alternative way would be you can directly curl the `POD_IP:80`

Answer (score 1):

The DNS name is referred incorrectly, it follows the following format

```
my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example
```

Based on the kubectl output, the DNS should be

```
echo-server.web-analytics.svc.cluster.local
```

The respective curl will be -

```
kubectl exec -it curl-curl0 -- curl http://echo-server.web-analytics.svc.cluster.local/heythere
```